# Spring @Scheduled job - Get base application path

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application and in it I am running a periodic job using a class with method annotated as `@Scheduled`

In this method, I want to get the base application path i.e. `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://www.mywebsite.com/` based on whether this is my local system or production system.

How can I do this? I do not have access to HttpServletRequest because this is not a Controller class.

Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion it is a good idea to use profiles and store properties like base application path in properties file - where each environment has its own property file: config_dev.properties, config_production.properties

Once they are there you can load them in job-like classes using Environment (described on [SpringSource blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)).

How to configure Tomcat and Spring to use profiles: [Spring 3.1 profiles and Tomcat configuration](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/03/27/spring-3-1-profiles-and-tomcat-configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

Put a `myconfiguration.properties` out of your application, to let the application know that whether its running locally or in production. And then in your method annotated as `@Scheduled` just read the `Property` file.

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("config.file.path");
File file = new File(configPath);
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(fileInput);
```

And provide the agrument,

```
-Dconfig.file.path=/path/to/myconfiguration.properties
```

when running your application server (or container). This can be done by putting,

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dconfig.file.path=/path/to/myconfiguration.properties"
```

at the beginning (roughly) of the script, which is used while running your application server.

- For tomcat its `catalina.sh`
- For Jboss AS its `run.sh`
- For weblogic its `setDomainEnv.sh`

And After doing that start your server and deploy your application. Finally, your `@Scheduled` method should know the information it needs. As the property file is outside of the application, you can change the value of the property when you want without rebuilding the application or without even disturbing it!

Answer (score 1):

just add this code in your web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>my.root.path</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and use it your code as a system properties